# Why can't I have an HID descriptor for a gamepad with 17 buttons?

Tags: c, hid, gamepad

I currently have this HID report descriptor:

```
    static
unsigned char hid_report_descriptor[] __attribute__ ((aligned(64))) = {
    0x05, 0x01,     // Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
    0x09, 0x05,     // Usage (Game Pad)
    0xA1, 0x01,     // Collection (Application)
    0xA1, 0x00,     //   Collection (Physical)
    0x85, 0x01,     //     Report ID (1)
    0x05, 0x09,     //     Usage Page (Button)
    0x19, 0x01,     //     Usage Minimum (0x01)
    0x29, 0x10,     //     Usage Maximum (0x10)
    0x15, 0x00,     //     Logical Minimum (0)
    0x25, 0x01,     //     Logical Maximum (1)
    0x95, 0x10,     //     Report Count (16)
    0x75, 0x01,     //     Report Size (1)
    0x81, 0x02,     //     Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
    0x05, 0x01,     //     Usage Page (Generic Desktop Ctrls)
    0x09, 0x30,     //     Usage (X)
    0x09, 0x31,     //     Usage (Y)
    0x09, 0x32,     //     Usage (Z)
    0x09, 0x33,     //     Usage (Rx)
    0x15, 0x81,     //     Logical Minimum (-127)
    0x25, 0x7F,     //     Logical Maximum (127)
    0x75, 0x08,     //     Report Size (8)
    0x95, 0x04,     //     Report Count (4)
    0x81, 0x02,     //     Input (Data,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
    0xC0,           //   End Collection
    0xC0,           // End Collection
};
```

It corresponds to this struct.

```
struct GamepadReport {
    uint8_t report_id;
    uint16_t buttons;
    int8_t left_x;
    int8_t left_y;
    int8_t right_x;
    int8_t right_y;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

I'm trying to add support for a *single extra button* that should serve as the "home" button (think of the X on an Xbox controller). This, in theory, should be done by changing the lines containing `0x29, 0x10` and `0x95, 0x10` to `0x29, 0x11` and `0x95, 0x11` respectively. However, doing so breaks the connection with the custom controller.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is and it makes absolutely zero sense to me. Can someone with more experience or knowledge about HID descriptors give me a hand?

Comment: Define "breaks the connection"?

Comment: Your report layout has 16 bits to hold buttons. Where is the 17th button supposed to go?

Comment: Yes pretty sure `uint16_t buttons;` has 16 bits for you not 17.

Comment: Perhaps you can add a second use page for buttons?

Comment: @user253751 The controller immediately disconnects upon connecting when I make the HID descriptor hold 17 buttons.

Comment: The *controller* disconnects? Or the *computer you plug it into* refuses to talk to the controller because it's speaking nonsense?

Comment: I'll try making some modifications based on your comments, I did already try playing around with the size of the buttons prop to no avail though.

Comment: @user253751 Probably the latter.

Comment: If the computer is running Linux, it will probably log something into the `dmesg` log

Comment: Changed the buttons prop size to unit32_t and it's still broken. Most likely because I have to change some other value somewhere. Adding a second usage page didn't work either. Back to square one.

Comment: Yes, the report structure has to match the structure of the report, but it's not what *defines* the structure of the report - that is the HID descriptor.

Comment: My guess: you have to change it to uint32 (or 16+8) and then also tell the computer you did that by editing the descriptor to define some padding bits

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone stumbles upon this or has a similar issue. You can't create a report count field on hid descriptors with numbers not divisible by 8 unless you add padding bits.

The solution was straightforward after reviewing the comments on my question and looking at similar issues online.

1. My gamepad report struct could only hold 16 bits. Even if I had a correctly defined hid descriptor, this would've prevented it from working. I changed my struct to the following.

```
struct GamepadReport {
    uint8_t report_id;
    uint32_t buttons;
    int8_t left_x;
    int8_t left_y;
    int8_t right_x;
    int8_t right_y;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

2. Modify your hid descriptor to contain the padding bits to the next number divisible by 8 that fits within your struct types. In this case, I need to fill 32 bits and I have 17 buttons. 32 - 17 means I need to add 15 padding bits.

```
        0x75, 0xF,         //     Report Size (15) - PADDING BITS
        0x95, 0x01,        //     Report Count (1)
        0x81, 0x03,        //     Input (Const,Var,Abs,No Wrap,Linear,Preferred State,No Null Position)
```

Comment: I expect they don't have to be divisible by 8, but they do when you're using fields of a struct to store them